# How to make a horizontal navbar for angular material

Tags: angularjs, navbar, angular-material

It's my first time using Angular Material and I'm just asking if you guys can help me on adding an horizontal nav bar for my project using Angular Material? I'm having some trouble looking for one. Thank you in advance! Stay awesome :)

Comment: They have added navbar tool in new release v1.1.0-RC.5 here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/navBar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at this example:

```
<div layout="row" layout-padding class="bg-dark-blue nav-dark" layout-align="space-between center">
<div>
    <md-button>Home</md-button>
    <md-button>Item 1</md-button>
    <md-button>Item 2</md-button>
    <md-menu>
        <md-button md-menu-origin ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Help</md-button>
        <md-menu-content width="2">
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button>Help</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button>About</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
</div>
<div class="nav-buttons">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-accent">My profile</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-warn">Log Out</md-button>
</div>
```

Some of it's classes are just for colorizing the content,don't pay attention to much to them :)

Comment: wow this is cool. but this is not responsive though. can you teach me? :D

Comment: Check the API Reference for layout options, You can add layout-sm &... to make it responsive

Answer (score 9):

As per [the official documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar), the horizontal navbar creation is as easy as using a `md-toolbar`.

```
    <md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z3" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;position:fixed;">
<h2>Sample navbar</h2>
</md-toolbar>`
```

You can add as many items you want inside the navbar and alignment of each items can be fixed using `<span flex></span>`.

In the span flex we can also specify values to it for specific alignments.

Answer (score 3):

This is how u create a navbar in angular material:
(I have used angular-material-icons here too:)

```
<md-content class="md-padding" style="background:#086A87">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">
              <ng-md-icon icon="phone" style="fill:wheat" size="20"></ng-md-icon>Personal Information
      </md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">
              <ng-md-icon icon="mode_edit" style="fill: wheat" size="20"></ng-md-icon>Edit
      </md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">
              <ng-md-icon icon="print" style="fill: wheat" size="20"></ng-md-icon>Print Detail1
      </md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page4')" name="page4">
                <ng-md-icon icon="print" style="fill: wheat" size="20"></ng-md-icon>Print Detail2      
      </md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>
</md-content>
```